# GPUImage and AVAssetWriter writes files to where?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, gpuimage, avassetwriter

I am trying to use Brad Larson's GPUImage library to record a video file. So far, the issue I am running into is the following piece of code:

```
NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"];
unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]); // If a file already exists, AVAssetWriter won't let you record new frames, so delete the old movie
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];
movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(480.0, 640.0)];
```

This is picked up directly from his example from his GitHub page
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Now, I looked at the source code and I see he does the usual AVFoundation stuff - creates AVAssetWriter instance and adds inputs to it. MY question here is that where is **@"Documents/Movie.m4v"** located? How can I play this video back? Or how do I even access it? I know it is located in an arbitrary location where the app bundle is copied during run-time. My goal is to be able to write the video into the Gallery or atleast an album in Gallery that is created by my app. Does anyone know where the file is being written to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but the movie is at the path `pathToMovie` (or URL `movieURL`.

You can play it back with something like this:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

// later
AVPlayerViewController *avc = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
avc.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:movieURL];
[myViewController presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you want to download the file to your computer, you can select your connect device in Xcode > Devices, then select your app and download the package. Your movie will be in the Documents directory.

To save it to the gallery, do

```
// TODO: use completion arguments for a better user experience
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathToMovie,nil,nil,nil);
```

Comment: Yes you are right. For some reason, my brain froze up there and I couldn't comprehend how to access the path.

Quick question though, when i try to access AVPlayerViewController, XCode gives me the error message: Unknown typename: AVPlayerViewController. This has to be an XCode bug because I see documentation for it and I have the AVFoundation framework included and am using other AV classes - AVCaptureSession, AVAssetWriter etc.

Right now I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play the video but it is being deprecated so would like to avoid it

Comment: Have you imported AVKit.h?

Comment: Yes I had. I fixed the issue by doing a clean and then a build. I guess something was mucked up.. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I have a follow up question of sorts. To create a gallery of videos that are in the Documents folder of my app, do I use MPMediaPickerController and set the source of data to my app's Document folder? Or is there another framework I can use to display a list of items? I want to provide this in the "gallery" of my app and then provide an option to save it to the main Photo Gallery. I have seen this feature in other apps and am wondering what is the best way to implement this without doing it from scratch?

Comment: There are surely cocoapods for this, but can you start a new question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705008/create-a-gallery-for-local-app-content-in-ios